# AMD Catalyst Beta Open Source Drivers

Tags: drivers

I'm a gamer with a pretty low-end computer, so I always update to the beta drivers to squeeze out every bit of performance I can get. I currently have 13.3 installed, but I want to install the 14.6 beta. I want to use the open source version, instead of downloading from AMD's website. How can I do that in the terminal? And please explain what the commands mean so I can do it on my own in the future. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you are in a bit of confusion. There is nothing like "14.6 beta open source version". The 14.6 beta driver(and all other drivers you get by using `apt-get install fglrx` or from the AMD website) are all called proprietary drivers(which means that they are released by AMD and not open source but closed source). The open source drivers are the ones installed default in Ubuntu. To use them you just have to remove all the proprietary drivers and thats all(if you haven't already purged the open source drivers).

Comment: You don't use Beta graphics drivers, ever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to install the 14.6 beta. I want to use the open source
>   version, instead of downloading from AMD's website

Well, you either use the open source drivers or the latest beta drivers(Also called 'proprietary' drivers) which is not open source. For the open source drivers you can open the Dash(Press <kbd>Super</kbd> key aka <kbd>Windows</kbd> key). Then start typing 'Additional drivers'. When you open the Additional drivers window you will something similar to this :-

[image]

There(as it is seen above) select the one that says `open source, tested` and you will be using the open source drivers.

For the latest beta you need to [take this](http://www2.ati.com/drivers/beta/linux-amd-catalyst-14.6-beta-v1.0-may23.zip).

Comment: Oh, I thought there was an open source equivalent for each proprietary release, thanks!